# Script para atualização GIT

Tags: linux, git, versionamento, shell-script

Estou com uma dúvida e não sei como resolver.
Acontece o seguinte, eu criei um script em `sh` chamado `atualiza.sh` dentro dele tenho o seguinte código.

```
git add .
git commit -m"atualiza rotina"
git push
xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Meu objetivo é, rodar uma rotina todos os dias que atualiza de forma automática qualquer mudança no git e envia para meu servidor de versionamento.
Só que quando a rotina executa esse arquivo `sh` que criei nada acontece. Alguém sabe me dizer qual é o erro?

Comment: Tem algum log? Talvez aí seja o caminho para descobrimos. Ou talvez adicionando `> log.txt` ao final do comando, você descubra o que está de errado.

Comment: Não retorna nada no log :(

Comment: Se de fato os comandos acima estão no script, algo deveria aparecer. Existe algum pedaço do script antes do que você postou? Que comando você está usando para executar o script?

Comment: Seu arquivo atualiza.sh está dentro do diretório do projeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte

Crie um script assim

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/{user}/localDoScript/atualiza.sh 
/usr/bin/git add -A 
/usr/bin/git commit -am "Atualiza rotina`date`"
/usr/bin/git push
```

No cron adicione ele para executar diariamente no horário desejado

```
* 22 * * * cd /home/{user}/localDoScript/ && ./atualiza.sh
```

neste caso todos os dias às 22hrs

Comment: Deu certo, valeu!